# Eclipse JFrame warning

Tags: java, eclipse

I often use JFrames, and because they are applications, they obviously need a

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

method. They also need the line in main()

```
myJFrame g = new myJFrame();
```

In eclipse, I get a warning on variable g: "The local variable g is never read", but if I omit that line, the program won't run. Why do I need that line, and if g is essential, why is there a warning on it?

Comment: Unless you actually do something later with the variable `g` or reference it in some way, you can get away with just doing `new myJFrame();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning means that you declare a local variable/pointer (called g in this case) but never actually utilize it anywhere in your code. With the warning the program should run fine, but you have a extra "pointer" to your JFrame that's never used.

If you want to access your JFrame from the method were you called `myJFrame g = new myJFrame();` you should keep it that way.
Otherwise `new myJFrame();` will suffice.

Answer (score 4):

Answering your question - probably you invoke all necessary methods (like `setVisible(true)` etc.) to run application in `myJFrame` constructor. If so - you needn't `g` local variable - you never use it later (looking at warning).

First thing `main` - is starting point of all Java applications.
Second thing if you doing all things in your `JFrame` constructor then you only need line

```
new myJFrame(); //in Java it's convention to use first letter 
                //upper-case class names -> MyJFrame
```

Below is simple, standard way of running first window in your application.

```
public final class App {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainWindow frame = new MainWindow();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In `MainWindow` class you only create Swing components etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not intending to reference this object ones initialized this wld be enough.

```
new myJFrame();
```